# Feeding an array to printfn

Tags: f#, printf

I'm printing a Tic-Tac-Toe board. I have an array of characters for each cell of the board and a format string for the board. I'm currently doing:

```
let cells = [| 'X'; 'O'; 'X'; 'O'; 'X'; 'O'; ' '; ' '; ' ' |]
printfn ".===.===.===.\n\
         | %c | %c | %c |\n\
         .===.===.===.\n\
         | %c | %c | %c |\n\
         .===.===.===.\n\
         | %c | %c | %c |\n\
         .===.===.===.\n" cells.[0] cells.[1] cells.[2] cells.[3] cells.[4] cells.[5] cells.[6] cells.[7] cells.[8]
```

Is there a way to feed the cells array to printfn without explicitly enumerating all 9 items in the array? Could I use Array.fold or kprintf somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funk's answer is pretty good, but I think you can make it simpler by introducing a `join` function to concatenate elements (individual cells or rows) with separators between them and surrounding them.

```
let join s arr = sprintf "%s%s%s" s (String.concat s arr) s
```

Then you can do this:

```
cells
|> Seq.chunkBySize 3
|> Seq.map (Seq.map (sprintf " %c ") >> join "|")
|> Seq.map (fun s -> s + "\n")
|> join ".===.===.===.\n"
|> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: Now that's more like it!

Answer (score 4):

It's far from sexy, but there's a pattern to be found.

```
cells
|> Array.toList
|> List.chunkBySize 3
|> List.fold 
    (fun acc list -> acc + 
                     (list |> List.fold (fun acc char -> acc + sprintf "| %c " char) "") + 
                     "|\n.===.===.===.\n") 
    ".===.===.===.\n"
|> printf "%s"
```

Answer (score 3):

Every successive application of an argument to the function results in a different type. For example:

```
let f1 = printfn "%d %d %d"  // f1 : int -> int -> int -> unit
let f2 = f1 0  // f2 : int -> int -> unit
let f3 = f2 1  // f3 : int -> unit
let r = f3 2   // r  : unit
```

Notice how `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `r` all have different types. Different types mean that you can't shove them into a generic data structure, such as a list or a sequence.

(to be honest, there is a way to go about this using method overloads, but that tends to break the compiler and generally is not necessary for real applications)

I would rather go a different route:

```
for i in 0..2 do
  printf ".===.===.===.\n|"
  for j in 0..2 do
    printf "%c |" cells.[i*3+j]
  printfn ""
printfn ".===.===.===."
```